# JS Websockets - still reconnecting until it's successful

Tags: javascript, websocket

I need to connect to websocket even if the first attemp is not successful. I need some loop.

Now I have:

```
 ws = new WebSocket('ws://domain');
 if(!ws) return; 
 ws.onopen = function() {
                ws.send('getpayments '+ response );
 }; ...
```

and I need do this until connect.
Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really a loop but recursive retries:

```
var retry_connecting = function(domain, clb) {
    var ws = new WebSocket(domain);
    ws.onerror = function() {
        console.log('WS Error! Retrying...');

        // let the client breath for 100 millis
        setTimeout(function() {
            retry_connecting(domain, clb);
        }, 100);
    };
    ws.onopen = function() {
        clb(ws);
    };
};
```

and usage

```
retry_connecting('ws://domain', function(ws) {
    console.log('We are connected!');
});
```

This code will try to connect ad infinitum. I don't recommend that. But I'm sure you'll be able to modify it to run only a finite number of times and then return an error after too many retries.